# How do i call C++ function from a JSP

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have called C++ function from Java by using Java Native interface, but now I want to use these java native interface in JSP. So how to use java native interface in a java web project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. JSPs are for templating, not calling code. Keep your business logic elsewhere, and pass the result along in a session variable you can pull out with JSTL.

If you absolutely insist on doing it from a JSP, scriptlets are really just Java code, anyway. The fact that this is JNI (since you've already got that working) is irrelevant. You just have some Java interface you're interacting with.